# Firebase Authentication User UID as child node in Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a folder in my Realtime Database called "users" with the unique identifier being the UID Firebase creates.

This code worked a few months ago. But it doesn't anymore. Frankly, I've made so many changes, I don't know if it was something I deleted... But I can't find what's wrong. The user gets created, but nothing gets written inside "users" in my Realtime Database.

```
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(SignUpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(inputEmail.getText().toString(),inputPassword.getText().toString());
                            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(inputEmail.getText().toString(),inputPassword.getText().toString());
                                FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
                                String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();
                                final User newuser = new User(signupInputUsername.getText().toString().trim(), inputEmail.getText().toString().trim(), inputPassword.getText().toString().trim(),
                                        gender.getText().toString().trim(), age.getText().toString().trim());
                                mDatabase.child("users").child(userid).setValue(newuser);
                                startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, UserActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });

 @IgnoreExtraProperties
public static class User {

    public String username, inputEmail, inputPassword, gender, age;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public User(String username, String inputEmail, String inputPassword, String gender, String age) {
        this.username = username;
        this.inputEmail = inputEmail;
        this.inputPassword = inputPassword;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

Comment: check db rules. do you get any errors ?

Comment: moreover .setvalue gives you a task and you are moving to the nex activity before the completion which might cancel the task

Comment: Your code isn't checking for errors anywhere at all in the calls you're making to the Firebase APIs.  Things could be going wrong, and you'd never know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the following code its from your code

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(userid).setValue(newuser);
startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, UserActivity.class));
finish();
```

the method `.setValue` actually gives you a task its not a void function so you should attach a listener to it and look if the the task was completed.

if it worked before it was still a problem in your code.

moreover look for the db rules if they are ok.